# Question about lynx text browser

Tags: 12.04, command-line, curl, lynx

When I go to visit this url

```
https://github.com/search?q=jquery+stars%3A>10+forks%3A<10&type=Repositories
```

using this command for lynx:

```
lynx -accept_all_cookies https://github.com/search?q=jquery+stars%3A>10+forks%3A<10&type=Repositories
```

First I get a code like this -> `[1] 4324` then another line which says -> `bash: 10: No such file or directory`

So, question is how can I browse this url url lynx? Also I can not `curl` this url , curl also showing nearly like same.

I am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your URL contains special characters that are being interpreted by the shell because you are not quoting it. So, short answer, use quotes:

```
lynx -accept_all_cookies 'https://github.com/search?q=jquery+stars%3A>10+forks%3A<10&type=Repositories'
```

Long answer: The specific issues here are `>10` and `&`. The `&` sends a job to the background:

```
$ sleep 5 &
[1] 2015
```

Note that the above causes a similar message to appear, the number in brackets is the job ID, in this case `1` since it is the only job running in the background and the other number is the process ID (PID) of the backgrounded process.

The next issue is the `<10` which means "read input from the file called '10' and `>10` which the shell interprets as "redirect output to a file called '10'`. For example:

```
$ echo "Hello" > 10
$ cat 10
Hello
```

All of these issues can be avoided if you simply quote such things, quoting will protect special characters from being interpreted by the shell.

Comment: It works! Thanks for your excellent explanation!

Answer (score 3):

Bash is interpreting the URL. The `<` and `&` mean things to it so they're being ripped around and aren't being passed to lynx.

The simple answer is to quote the url:

```
lynx -accept_all_cookies 'https://github.com/search?q=jquery+stars%3A>10+forks%3A<10&type=Repositories'
```

I'm using single quotes here so that even `$` isn't interpreted.

Comment: Thank you, now it's working! I am new in ubuntu, just learned a new things very useful from you.